# Take when id not equal in laravel

Tags: laravel

This is my code:

```
$question = message::with('category')->where([['id', $id], ['type', 1]])->whereColumn([['id', 'f_id']])->first();
$sameid=$question['fcat_id'];
$similar=message::orderBy('id','DESC')->where([['fcat_id',$sameid],['type',1],['answer',2]])->whereColumn('id','f_id')->take(6)->select('id','title')->get();
```

i want in `$similar` take when id in similar not equal with `$question`.
how can do i it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another condition in your `where()` function which contains `['id', '!=', $question->id]` for `$similar`.

```
$similar=message::orderBy('id','DESC')->where([['fcat_id',$sameid],['type',1],['answer',2],['id', '!=', $question->id]])->whereColumn('id','f_id')->take(6)->select('id','title')->get();
```